# How to exit terminal automatically after exiting tmux

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, tmux, gnome-terminal

I am not sure whether similar questions were asked, but I did't find in SO.

I am using gnome-terminal + tmux. I've add `if [ "$TMUX" = "" ]; then tmux; fi` in my `.zshrc` so when I start terminal, I enter tmux automatically. Every time I press `Ctrl-D` and quit from the tmux, I have to press `Ctrl-D` again to quit from the terminal.

Now, what can I put in my `.zshrc` or `tmux.conf` so as to quit my tmux and terminal with only one press.

What I thought is that I can add a listener to capture tmux exiting event. And if that event occurs, let me quit from the window. But I have no idea how to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I forgot to state how I start tmux, I will reedit my question now.

Comment: BTW, for future note, questions about interactive shell use (as opposed to scripting) are often a better fit for [unix.se] or SuperUser.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, Thanks for the remind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you start `tmux` with `exec`, as in:

```
exec tmux
```

...the parent-process shell will no longer even be in memory, so exiting tmux won't quit back to it.

---

Thus, in your dotfiles:

```
if [ -t 0 ] && [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ $- = *i* ]]; then exec tmux; fi
```

`[ -t 0 ]` is a safety feature: It avoids moving forward if your stdin is not a TTY. Similarly, the `$-` check avoids running on non-interactive shells.

---

By the way -- I would generally advise making this part of your *terminal* configuration, not part of your *shell* configuration, to avoid inadvertently impacting other kinds of shells (such as ones started via sshd, particularly by an automated tool rather than a human user). Scripts *shouldn't* simulate TTYs, or claim to a shell that they're interactive when they aren't, but it happens in practice, and this kind of practice can thus lead to surprises.

Comment: But I am using Ubuntu18 gnome-terminal, I haven't found the terminal configuration file.  I use zsh for my default shell, so I put it in my `.zshrc`.

Comment: Been a while since I used GNOME, but I remember it being configurable via clicking around GUI menus.

Comment: ...per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81165/use-a-different-shell-by-default-in-each-terminal-emulator, there should be an option to use a custom command instead of invoking your default shell in the gnome-terminal profile editor.